# I deleted var folder accidentally in my ubuntu 12.04. please help me to get back my home folder

Tags: 12.04, data-recovery, directory, permanent-delete

I did something really stupid. I apologize!!  I just wanted to learn laravel framework and installed.

The bad time came to use "gulp" command in terminal.

Next what all happened I don't know. My sudo stopped working network(wifi, LAN, Bluetooth, USB) also stopped working. In the middle often my hard disk(**`/dev/sda1`**) automatically shows full. Yesterday when I start computer shows graphics error.. pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> got terminal and accidentally typed `rm -rf /var/*`

Please help me to get my data back please please..

Comment: Boot from LiveUSB and copy your files.

Comment: I'm a newbie to Ubuntu. How to achieve that.. would you please tell me the procedure.

Comment: Download an Ubuntu ISO, burn it to a USB and boot from it.

Comment: As I said in question, My USB is not working and are you saying about reinstall? If yes then how to achieve it please. I'm really sorry because I'm a newbie to Ubuntu :(

Comment: You need to create LiveUSB on another computer. You can find directions in the net.

Comment: Could you please send me some links to achieve that. Because I am in position of last chance to get the data. If I do wrong in this case, my data will go permanently!!

Comment: General instructions for data recovery process: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: Just an FYI: Ubuntu 12.04 will die off and no longer be supported in April 2017.

Comment: I have installed ubuntu 14.04 through try ubuntu. I have tried below command. it shows omitting folder. Please help

Answer (score 0):

These are detailed steps for performing the first suggestion provided by Pilot6 in the comment section of your question.

**Boot from a LiveUSB or LiveDVD**

You will need the type of media you used to install Ubuntu the first time.  Find this USB or DVD disk and boot to it.  Once the system has booted choose the option that says **Try Ubuntu**.

**Mount the partition where Ubuntu is installed.**

You can find where Ubuntu is installed by running the **Gnome Disk Utility**.  Type `disks` in the Ubuntu launch button and click on the app.

Now look for your installation partition by clicking on one of the items on the left.  Your installation will be on the `/dev/sda` drive by default.  So select the one that has `/dev/sda` in the title bar of the application's window.

Now look at the descriptions under the **Volumes** section.  Find the one that has **Ext4** in the descript.  That will be your **installation partition**.

Run these commands, one by one, to mount and copy the **/var** directory from your Live Session to your system.

Open a **Terminal** by typing `terminal` in the Ubuntu Launch button.  Click on the **Terminal** app.

Perform these steps in the black screen (the terminal).

```
1) $ sudo mount /dev/sda# /mnt
   (Replace the # with the number where you have identified as the Ext4 partition
   of your /dev/sda drive)
2) $ mkdir /mnt/var
3) $ sudo cp /var/* /mnt/var/
4) $ sudo umount /mnt
```

Now close the running apps and reboot.  The system will prompt you to eject the live media.

Comment: I want to achieve it through liveusb. right now I'm having 16gb pendrive, 1tb hardisk, not working laptop which is having my deleted data. which file I have to download from net..tell me the procedure step by step please...

Comment: @YanaShetty [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS direct download link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/)].  Download the **ISO** image and burn it to your pendrive.  You'll have to burn it from the computer you're using to type your messages.  Then after you burn the image to the Pendrive, boot your computer to that drive.  By the way, do you remember where the USB/DVD is that you originally used for installing Ubuntu?  If you can find that one, that is the one you can conveniently use.  After you boot to the Pendrive, follow the steps in the answer.

Comment: My laptop is Compaq 325( AMD processor).which one I have to download from http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/

Comment: The first one in the list.

Comment: Thank you☺ I'm downloading now and once I copied to my pendrive and inserted into PC and what is the next step.. before loading is there to press esc or something. Please help I'm newbie to Ubuntu and I lost my data

Comment: Burn the ISO file to a Pendrive (as I mentioned in the previous message).  This is what you originally did when you first installed Ubuntu.  Do the same.  Burn it to a Pendrive, then boot to that USB Pendrive.  After you boot, follow the steps provided in the answer.

Comment: I can get my data know if I used `rm -rf /var/*`.

Comment: if I run above command it shows

cp: omitting directory '/var/backups'

cp: omitting directory '/var/cache'

cp: omitting directory '/var/lib'

cp: omitting directory '/var/local'

cp: omitting directory '/var/log'

cp: omitting directory '/var/mail'

cp: omitting directory '/var/metrics'

cp: omitting directory '/var/opt'

cp: omitting directory '/var/run' 

cp: omitting directory '/var/spool' 

cp: omitting directory '/var/tmp'