# Kubuntu 18.04 deleted /var, won't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu, kde

Like a massive noob I deleted all of /var on my Kubuntu 18.04 install (dual booted with Windows). Now when I try to boot Kubuntu from grub it hangs in the OEM's logo. I can boot from recovary and even get the GUI working with startx.

I tried the suggestion here: [I deleted var folder accidentally in my ubuntu 12.04. please help me to get back my home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/876198/i-deleted-var-folder-accidentally-in-my-ubuntu-12-04-please-help-me-to-get-back)
Which is too live boot iso, mount my install partition and then copy the live /var. So I know have a /var directory that looks roughly right, but Kubuntu still isn't booting properly.

Any ideas what could be the issue and or ways to fix it? Or just go for reinstall route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not worth spending time with, you may have plenty of things there since you installed which just are not  on boot disk. Just reinstall.